# Antlr - not able to use Lexer token if it is assigned to another token in grammar

Tags: antlr4

> ```
> "In this example if i use 'MID('int = VALUE')' then it works fine. I want MID to be validated for INT value but when i use INT it gives error "mismatched input '9' expecting INT.
> ```
>
> I am using antlr-4.2-complete version of antlr.
>   I am not able to understand the exact issue?

```
grammar DIExpression;

r: 'MID('int_val = INT')'
    {
        System.out.println("value equals: "+ $int_val.text); 
    };

VALUE : INT | STRING;
STRING : [0-9a-zA-Z_]+;
INT : [0-9]+;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

**UPDATE:**

I am giving input like MID(9)

Comment: Not sure I understand you right and I only worked with antlr3 but if you want MID to be validated I am pretty sure you should not put it in 'quotes'. Please post an example of what you give as input and the expected Result

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your rules are ambiguous. What should '9' be? It could be a STRING or and INT. I would highly recommend to use the predefined literals for STRING, WS, COMMENT and NEWLINE provided by the antlr community.

**Be aware, this is antlr3 code!** As you can see a String is sth in quotes (I guess that´s also what you want)

```
INT :   '0'..'9'+
    ;

FLOAT
    :   ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* EXPONENT?
    |   '.' ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT?
    |   ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    |   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

STRING
    :  '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
    ;

CHAR:  '\'' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\''|'\\') ) '\''
    ;

fragment
EXPONENT : ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? ('0'..'9')+ ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    |   OCTAL_ESC
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks!!
i am giving input like MID(9).

Comment: And if I put " VALUE : INT ;" instead VALUE : INT | STRING; then also the above code doesn't work.
So, I have to put VALUE in MID like  'MID('int_val = VALUE ')' or if I want put INT then I have to remove or comment "VALUE : INT | STRING;" statement .

Comment: As far as I understand your requirement I think you want be able to parse
MID(9) as well as MID("9"), right? anything else does not make sense to me. So the main problem with your lexer rules is, that your "String" does not include quotes so the parser cannot decide if 9 is should be interpreted as string or as int. 
If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as solved. ty